# MAC OSX : PHP_startup unable to load dynamic library php_soap.so

Tags: php, web-services, macos, soap

I was trying to enable the soap.so extension but here's what echoing when trying to generate the .wsdl

```
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_soap.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_soap.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm running PHP 5.3.2 on MACOS X **10.6.4**

What i have to do to fix that error please ?

`php -m` tells me that soap.so is activated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrading to PHP 5.3.3 and compiling it on MAC will resolve the problem : 
http://www.bdoran.co.uk/2010/08/03/installing-php-soap-on-osx-leopard-10-6-4/

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Mac OS X and after having a handful of problems with using the built-in PHP with SOAP, I went with MAMP, and it has worked like a charm.

Comment: i'd rather use the default configuration if that's possible :/