# ERROR : Installing a new version of PHP on MAC

Tags: php, macos, compilation, makefile

i'm trying to enable the php_soap module for mac so i follow some tutorial to answer my own question ( [MAC OSX : PHP_startup unable to load dynamic library php_soap.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142578/mac-osx-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-soap-so))

**Here is the tutorial** >> http://www.bdoran.co.uk/2010/08/03/installing-php-soap-on-osx-leopard-10-6-4/

1) I replaced `curl -O http://de3.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.1.tar.bz2` with

```
curl -O http://de3.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.3.tar.bz2
```

2) When the tutoral tells to do :

```
cd ext/php
```

just before doing `phpize`

it tells me *cd: ext/php: No such file or directory*

How to bypass that probelm to run `phpize` and to follow the tutorial in order to enable this freaking SOAP module please ?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `mkdir ext/php`?

Comment: if i try to create the folder : when i run phpize it tells me : Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just doing the usual "./configure ; make" type process? There is no php/ext dir in the distribution you're downloading, so the tutorial obviously doesn't apply anymore. There maybe have been such a dir in 5.3.1, but it's obviously not there in 5.3.3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting a lot of traffic to my site from this forum.

I apologise I should have made it more clear that the set up was for just the specific build of OSX and PHP.

It worked with version up to 5.3.2, but after 5.3.3 the soap extension has moved to /etc/soap, you can now build it much easier :

`curl -O http://de3.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.3.tar.bz2`

`tar xjf php-5.3.3.tar.bz2`

`cd php-5.3.3`

`cd ext/soap`

`phpize`

`./configure`

`make`

`sudo make install`

I've also updated the tutorial for OSX Lion : http://www.bdoran.co.uk/2011/11/22/installing-php-soap-on-osx-lion-10-7-2 as I just had to reinstall the SOAP extension myself.

Again, apologies for not being clear on the versioning issue.

Answer (score -1):

you have to make sure that your sources which you fetched with curl actually are in that folder where you run phpize.

Comment: i do run phpize in the folder i've just downloaded via CURL.